# Why RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR() function is not working in this code?

Tags: plsql

I want to throw a customize error when the query fetches no record. But the below code is not throwing my desired error. It is throwing the system generated an error. Could you please help me? What mistake I am making?

```
DECLARE
v_em_id NUMBER := &var_id;
v_name varchar2(20);
BEGIN
SELECT first_name INTO v_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id =v_em_id;
IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'Employee not exist');
END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hi! '|| v_name);
END;
```

I should throw the error code:-20002
and error message: Employee not exist.

Comment: Can you please add the error that is being thrown?

Comment: @bogertron presumably it is an unhandled `no_data_found` due to the lack of an exception handler for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code...

```
DECLARE
  v_em_id NUMBER := &var_id;
  v_name  varchar2(20);
BEGIN

  SELECT first_name INTO v_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = v_em_id;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hi! ' || v_name);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Employee not exist');
    END IF;
END;
```

If the `select` statement returns no rows it will raise `no_data_found` exception. So system is failing before the `IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN` line..

Comment: It should be added that this is caused by the `into` clause, which expects the query to return exactly one row. In various other situations (like doing updates, or insert-selects), you won't get this exception, and `sql%rowcount` is the way to check the number of rows affected.